# Federated identity between multiple instances of IdSrv3

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

Is it possible to do federated identity between multiple instances of IdSrv3 using OpenID Connect/OAuth2 in the following scenario?

Multiple instance of IdSrv3, called Local STS, running on different machines with some kind of chain of trust to a Central STS. The machines running the Local STS can go offline and in that context the  applications running on the local machines makes call to local STS for a token and uses that token while communicating with APIs on another server. The API Service, which is registered and connected to the Central STS, can validate and trust the token generated by a Local STS.  Is it possible to do this setup with IdSrv3 or IdSrv4? Also how can a chain of trust be established  between central and local STS?

Answer (score 1):

That is absolutely possible -

in IdentityServer you can add external providers via ASP.NET (Core) authentication middleware. For the "other" IdentityServer this becomes a normal client.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityProviders.html